# How to call Google Maps Direction Webservice in Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I m new to android developement. In my application i need to read Data from google maps api direction webservice.

**http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false**

I want to call this webservice. And reading data from this link. Plz any one help me in this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call url with `HttpConnection`

```
public String getValuefromUrl(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
            Log.v("PAGE",page);
            return page;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "zero";  

        }
    }
```